# Gradle dependendy information

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies

Is it possible in gradle to get information about maven artifacts in the `dependencies` extension?

In my build.gradle I specified the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.0.6'
}
```

The specific informations I need are:

- The group (org.controlsfx)
- The name (controlsfx)
- The version (8.0.6)
- The download url (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/8.0.2/controlsfx-8.0.2.jar)

I need these informations about all the maven dependencies to write them into a file and
deploy it with the application, so the updater can read it and automatically download the newest build and the updated dependencies.

**EDIT**
This file should be generated by the gradle build script and contain name, version and url.
The updater can then compare the local file with the remote file and update only the jars
that are newer.

I know, all the dependencies are automatically downloaded by gradle, I just want to know how I could get access to these informations in my build script.

Comment: It sounds like the pom file for the artifact which exactly contains those information.

Comment: I don't understand. If build with gradle all the dependencies will be downloaded automatically.

Comment: I know, all the dependencies are automatically downloaded by gradle. But I need to save the dependency informations into a file. My updater can then compare the remote dependency file with the local one and decide what to update, and from where to download.

Comment: What do you mean with maven dependencies? Does your project contain a pom and you want the dependencies from the pom configuration? Or do you mean your dependencies defined in `build.gradle` downloaded from a maven repo?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about this. I updated the question to be a bit more precise. Thank you for taking a look at it.

Comment: The usual thing to do is to have Gradle download all your dependencies, build your software, and package it up *with all its dependencies* and then deploy that whole thing. From what I can understand, you want to 'update' and existing deployment with a new version of your software and only those dependencies that have changed - is that correct?

Comment: @PerrynFowler Exactly.